# Сменить simple_list_item_1 на simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Имеется ListView, содержащий элементы с разметкой `simple_list_item_1`. Хочется сделать так, чтобы, например, после долгого тапа разметка менялась на `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`, а далее производить с выбранными элементы дальнейшие действия. То бишь после тапа должна быть возможность отмечать элементы. Каким образом это реализуется?

Comment: В целом в 2017 лучше использовать RecyclerView. А по вопросу: можно, к примеру, сделать в одно разметке поверх еще одну, но присвоить ей visibility=gone, при клике - менять на visible.

Comment: @researcher спасибо за информацию, завтра почитаю о RecyclerView

Comment: это займет некоторое время разобраться, но о ListView лучше забыть и не использовать.